# No space left on device on newly installed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows. When I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` after installing I got this error.

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
unable to flush var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i after padding: No space left on device
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
```

I looked up the issues, and found the some which tried to resolve the issue, but most of them suggested `sudo apt clean` or `sudo apt autoclean` which doesn't work for me. I also saw one which tried to increase the size, but it doesn't seem to work for me although I may be doing it wrong.

I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu while following a guide to partition the disk, but the issue it comes up.

`df -h` shows

[image]

Can this be fixed by partitioning my disk in some way that I can still reinstall Ubuntu if that fixes the problem? Or how do I increase the size?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your image looks like a 'live' is running ('cow' or copy-on-write), that it's not installed, or if installed; it was just copied/cloned to a drive rather thatn 'installed'.  Please also copy & paste your text image (in the future ideally) into your question as text.  if you installed; maybe you didn't remove your 'live' media, and it booted again, so it's your install media you're running, and not your installed system?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue. Could you please post a solution if you found it? Thanks :)